# Elementary proof of this easy number-theoretic statement?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

We have the following very elementary statement:

Let $p$ be a prime number. Let $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ be an integer number and $d \in \mathbb{N}$ be a positive integer. Then there exists a positive integer $e \in \mathbb{N}$ and integers $n, m \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $0 \leq m < p^e$ and $0 \leq n < p^d$ such that
$$k = (p^d -1)m - p^e n.$$

The only proof I know of this is the following: consider the rational number $\alpha = \frac{k}{p^d-1}$. Because $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_{(p)}$ we can consider its $p$-adic expansion:
$$\alpha = \alpha_0 + p \alpha_1 + p^2 \alpha_2 + \cdots$$
Because $\alpha$ is rational with $(p^d -1) \alpha \in \mathbb{Z}$ this expansion is eventually repeating with period $d$ (see e.g. Konrad's notes [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/rationalsinQp.pdf), where it is only proven that the expansion is eventually repeating, but I believe it follows from the proof that $d$ is an eventual period for the expansion).

We can thus "chop-off" the expansion to obtain $\alpha = m + p^e \gamma$ where $0 \leq m < p^e$ is an integer and $\gamma \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ has a (purely) periodic expansion with period $d$. But on Konrad's notes (or just by observing) we also see that the periodicity of the expansion of $\gamma$ implies that $(p^d - 1)\gamma \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $-1 \leq \gamma \leq 0$ so $\gamma = -n/(p^d -1)$ for some integer $n$ with $0 \leq n < p^d -1$. Multiplying the equality by $\alpha = m + p^e \gamma$  by $(p^d -1)$ we obtain the required result.

My question is: is there an elementary proof of this that does not use $p$-adic integers?

The natural first attempt is to use the coprimality of $(p^d -1)$ and $p^e$ to write $k$ as $k = (p^d -1)a - p^e b$ for some $a,b$. We would want to pick $e$ such that $-p^e \leq k \leq (p^e-1)(p^d-1)$ ($\ast$) since this would follow it we could find the desired expression. Then use the fact that we can replace $a$ by $a + p^e$ and $b$ with $b + (p^d -1)$ in the expression above. But I could not get this to work: in fact, for the example $p = 2, d = 3, k = -19$ one needs to pick $e \geq 5$ so the inequality ($\ast$) is not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $k$ be a *positive* integer and let $e$ be such that $p^e>k$. The integers $p^d-1$ and $p^e$ are coprime, so there exist integers $a$ and $b$ such that
$$(p^d-1)a-p^eb=k.$$
Then for every integer $c$ we also have
$$(p^d-1)(a+p^ec)-p^e(b+(p^d-1)c)=k,\tag{1}$$
and there exists a unique integer $c_0$ such that $0\leq a+p^ec_0<p^e$. Define
$$m:=a+p^ec_0\qquad\text{ and }\qquad n:=b+(p^d-1)c_0,$$
so that $k=(p^d-1)m-p^en$ and $0\leq m<p^e$. Then it follows from $(1)$ that
$$n=b+(p^d-1)c_0=\frac{(p^d-1)(a+p^ec_0)-k}{p^e}<p^d-1-\frac{k}{p^e}<p^d,$$
and clearly $n\geq0$ as otherwise
$$k=(p^d-1)m-p^en\geq p^e>k,$$
a contradiction. The proof for negative $k$ is similar, and for $k=0$ we can take $m=n=0$.